# Cpanel Problem-This server is currently not licensed. Please contact the server administrator

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I try to login to cpanel and get the following error.
I loaded the page many times but nothing.After 10 hours I tried again and still nothing.
My servers is paid for 3 years so there is no case of expired liscence.
What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

**This server is currently not licensed. Please contact the server administrator. Other services available on this server such as web services are likely functioning normally. (Unknown License File Sum (has=,needed=20).**

**Once the license on this server is active, you will no longer see this message. If you have installed a license since loading this page, click here to reload.**

Answer (score 2):

> My servers is paid for 3 years so
>   there is no case of expired liscence.

Why not? With all respect - the error message is absolutely clear, jsut read what you posted.

Just because you PAID for it doesn ot mean that it was properly processed. Either you verlook something (cpanel licensing limits that you assume do not exist), or someone just made the mistake to now put the license file in, or you have to install it yourself and get it from your provider. All issues you should not raise on serverfault but on your providers support. We dont even know which provider (you dont care to tell us) and we definitely know leds about your licenses than he.

But really, even if you paid for something it does not mean that no errror happened somewhere in processing. Obviously something is bad here with your licensing. Raise it with the people you PAY for helping you.

Comment: +1; The answer was in the question: "Please contact the server administrator" which, if the OP doesn't know what's going on, is the provider.

Answer (score 2):

Did you purchase your license direct from cPanel or another provider?

If you visit http://verify.cpanel.net you can verify the license online in real time.

If it shows licensed - and is not working - I suggest opening a ticket online with cPanel directly.

If not - then contact the organization you purchased the license through.